# Determining if a family of sets of type $(-r,r)$ and $[-r,r]$ is a topology.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to determine if a family $\tau=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(-r,r):r\in\mathbb{R^+}\}\cup\{[-r,r]:r\in\mathbb{R^+}\}$ is a topology. The only condition I am struggling with is showing that the union of an arbitrary number of sets of the form $(-r_\alpha,r_\alpha)$ or $[-r_\alpha, r_\alpha]$ is also in $\tau$. I have $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{r_\alpha:r\in\Omega\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R^+}$. It seems clear to me that if this set is unbounded above, the union will be $\mathbb{R}$ and if it is bounded above by some $p\in\mathbb{R^+}$ it will be equal to either $(-p,p)$ or $[-p,p]$. However, I am struggling on how to formalize this thinking, or if it is even correct.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751095/proving-that-the-family-of-subsets-of-mathbbr-containing-symmetric-open-int) helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S,T\subseteq\mathbb R^+$, and let $r=\sup (S\cup T)$. Then you can show that

$$\bigcup\{(-s,s):s\in S\}\cup\bigcup\{[-t,t]:t\in T\}$$

is either $(-r,r)$ or $[-r,r]$. Either way, it belongs to the topology.